# How to mute fallback source sink in shell?

Tags: pulseaudio

Is there an easy way that does not involve inspecting large amount of output text?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: @waltinator Why? Wasn't the question clear to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: now I found the right solution:

```
pactl set-source-mute @DEFAULT_SOURCE@ 1
```

You can alternatively use `true` instead of `1` for muting and `false` or `0` for unmuting.